# What is this component on my dog's door opening collar?

Tags: components, identification, proximity-sensor

I am having some frustration with my dog's pet door opener. This is an off-the-shelf system from a company called HighTechPet, and the collar unit uses a coin-cell battery with a special carrier glued onto it in such a way that you cannot simply replace the battery alone: you have to order replacements with the carriers pre-attached (at a considerable mark-up) from the company.

Now, this would not be so egregious, except the batteries only last 2-3 months.

While I had the unit open for the second time, I thought I'd take a look at the circuit and try to see if the three-month lifespan is really the best that can be done. (Call me cynical, but I am suspecting not.)

Below are two pictures of the open unit with the component side of the PCB exposed.

[image: MS4-C top]
[image: MS4-C side]

The component labelled MS4-C is presumably some kind of ultrasonic transmitter. Here is what the Web site has to say:

> Our VP of Engineering, Bob Schilken, one of the most accomplished analog electronic engineers in the world, contributed the extremely creative directional ultrasonic detection circuitry that performs rings around conventional infared, magnetic and RFID circuits.

How might I go about finding more information on this component?

EDIT: Here are some oscilloscope traces sampled from the positive lead of the presumed ultrasonic transducer.

[image]

One thing that immediately catches my eye is that the lead is held high, and pings are produced by pulsing the line low with a signal that lasts 2-3ms every 25ms. Wouldn't having the line be normally high like this waste a lot of the coin cell battery power?

[image]

This trace is a zoomed-in view of a single ping. It appears to oscillate at 40kHz, which would put it well out of audible range (as you'd expect). I don't know why it's shaped like that, though… Some deliberate signal or just an artifact of the way the circuit and/or component behaves?

Comment: It looks like sound to me. I've seen some ultrasonic transducers in such sealed cases. Can you show us the bottom of the PCB? Do you have an oscilloscope available?

Comment: Okay, the bottom of the PCB shows that the component just has two terminals. I can get access to an oscilloscope sometime next week, so I'll update with more info then.

Comment: Sure, Mr. Schilken's ulrasonic detection performs circles out of RFID, except that, oh, RFID tags *don't require batteries*.

Comment: BS Alert! "*one of the most accomplished analog electronic engineers in the world*": Did that bit of hyperbole not alert you to the credibility of the claims? A quick Google search for patents and publications by the great Bob / Robert provides a reality check.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I've added some traces taken from the positive lead of the component, and asked some clarifying questions inline.

Comment: @Kaelin Colclasure I'm not sure right now why holding the line high would waste any power. I must admit that I haven't done any work with ultrasonic transducers, but if I had to drive it I'd most likely connect it's positive side to one power rail (possibly through a capacitor) and trigger the other side with a transistor. If they just tied one side high and trigger the other side with a transistor, it shouldn't waste power while it's off.

Comment: What does look wasteful to me is that the tag is constantly transmitting. If I wanted to maximize battery life, I'd use a system where the tag is passively receiving and the door mechanism is transmitting. Once tag gets in range, it would transmit back something. On the other hand, such solution using ultrasonic transducers would require at least half-duplex communication system while it seems that they're just using simplex right now.

Comment: Also if that transducer is directly connected to a power rail, then I think that some power consumption reduction could be achieved by placing a capacitor in parallel with it. If it's the power rail that's dipping, then a capacitor might increase battery lifetime since, if I remember correctly, coin cell batteries don't like bursts of current drain.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Good point about the high line not actually wasting power. I forget that potential does not necessarily imply current. I am far enough into this project now that I've ordered a "spare" collar unit that I will be sacrificing to my further education…

Comment: @AndrejaKo If you write up your comments as an answer, I can accept it. :-)

Comment: @AndrejaKo I don't know about ultrasonic but if this was RF then blindly transmitting with a low duty cycle would probably need less power than continuously listening to and decoding a signal.

Comment: Doesn't transmitting at 40kHz annoy the dog?