# Identity of TI mystery chip: CM060B

Tags: components, identification, ultrasound

I am having trouble identifying one of the two ICs on my dog's ultrasonic collar tag. The lettering on the 16-pin SOIC package was obscured by some sealant which I had to scrape away, leaving the markings quite faint, so it's possible I'm misreading them (and thus far I have found it impossible to get them to show up at all in a picture).

I can make out a TI logo, and there are three lines of markings which appear to read:

```
CM060B
49K _G4_  <-- That's an underlined G4
A995
```

The usual Google technique leads to lots of "In Stock!" and "Register to receive a quote" pages, but no datasheets.

Anyone know what this might be?

EDIT: The second IC on the tag is a quad two-input NAND gate. There is also some sort of crystal or oscillator in a tall, thin metal can (about the dimensions of a resistor but with both leads at the bottom); this appears to be the source of a very steady 40kHz sine wave. See [What is this component on my dog's door opening collar?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/what-is-this-component-on-my-dogs-door-opening-collar) for a wide shot of the PCB with the glue still covering the IC in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible that you scraped off part of the part number printing and that the part is actually like:

[image]

...implying a part number CD4060B ?

Comment: +1, I'd bet money that this is it: Most likely the CD4060BNSR, CD4060BNSRE4 or CD4060BNSRG4, going by the top side markings listed. "*CMOS 14-Stage Ripple-Carry Binary Counter/Divider and Oscillator*"

Comment: The M is fairly clear, and doesn't appear to be a D4. I'm still working on getting an image that shows the markings and will post it if I can.

Comment: I have no idea if this is the OP's chip, but +1 for the creativity. That's just awesome.

Comment: Ok, so now I do have an idea ;-) (I called and confirmed -- see my answer for details)

Answer (score 4):

### It's a TI CD4060

I called my contact at TI.

I can confirm that "CM060B" **is the device marking for a [CD4060](https://circuithub.com/parts/TI/CD4060BE/documents)**. You can verify independently by calling TI and using service reference 1-1046761093.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive follow-up! I was torn over which to mark as the accepted answer, and decided to go with the earlier one. I hope that's okay. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Of course that's ok. The other answer is technically wrong, since the marking is actually "CM060B" as you indicated, but I like that answer because its creative. We need more creativity in engineering.